# Создание фиксированной таблицы

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Решил сделать для себя упрощенный вариант "Морского боя" для Android.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: как сделать фиксированную 10х10 таблицу?
`GridView` выносит ошибку, мол, не могу найти `support library` (и выдает ошибку при попытке её скачивания)

Есть ещё какие-то варианты? Вот, что хотелось бы получить в итоге:

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1):

Самый тупой метод в лоб, это нарисовать png нужного вам размера, и в цикле добавлять в LinearLayout кнопки с фоном этой самой png.

А что по поводу support lib то ее можно скачать через Android SDK и уже потом подключить jar к проекту.

Comment: сейчас support lib автоматически должна добавляться при создании проекта и лучше все же использовать GridView. Надо будет написать свой апаптер.